# Como ignorar uma Serialização?

Tags: c#, serialização

Estou tendo problemas ao Serializar uma classe Socket com o `BinaryFormatter`, tentei usar o atributo `NonSerializedAttribute`, mas só que não dá certo para esse tipo de propriedade abaixo.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class Connection
{
    [NonSerializedAttribute]
    public Socket Socket { get; set; }
}
```

Estou serializando essa classe no parametro do método abaixo:

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object anySerializableObject)
{
     using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
     {
         (new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(memoryStream, anySerializableObject);
         return memoryStream.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Se eu não ignorar a serialização da classe Socket, vai dar esse erro:

> O tipo 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket' no assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' não está marcado como serializável.

O que faço para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: @ramaral, você tem razão. Ambos os atributos não funcionam com `BinaryFormatter`. Minha resposta estava equivocada, a apaguei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Esse atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) não pode ser aplicado em propriedades.

Para aplicar terá de transformar a auto propriedade numa com *backing field* e aplicar o atributo ao *backing field*.

```
[NonSerialized]
private Socket socket;

public Socket Socket 
{
    get 
    {
        return socket;
    }  
    set 
    { 
        socket = value; 
    }
}
```

C# 7.0

```
[NonSerialized]
private Socket socket;

public Socket Socket 
{
    get => socket;
    set => socket = value; 
}
```